# JsTree 3.2.1 checkbox issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jstree

Im working with jstre 3.2.1 with lazy loading and all is working fine.
this is Json class that i fill in my asp.net mvc5 action.

```
public class AutorisationNodeModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public List<AutorisationNodeModel> children { get; set; }
        public State state { get; set; }
    }

    public class State
    {
        public bool selected { get; set; }
    }
```

and the view

```
$("#AutorizationTree").jstree({
            "core": {
                "themes": {
                    "responsive": false
                },
                // so that create works
                "check_callback": true,
                'data': {
                    "type": "POST",
                    "dataType": "json",
                    'url': function (node) {
                        return '@Url.Action("GetTreeNodes", "Administration")';
                    },
                    'data': function (node) {
                        return { 'IdApplication': $('#AppSelectionne').val() };
                    }
                }
            },
            "types": {
                "default": {
                    "icon": "fa fa-folder icon-state-success icon-lg"
                },
                "file": {
                    "icon": "fa fa-file icon-state-success icon-lg"
                }
            },
            "plugins": ["dnd", "types", "checkbox", "json_data"],
            "checkbox": { "tie_selection": false }

        });
```

but pre selected nodes its not working please help me to resolve this issues

Comment: Why are you setting `"tie_selection": false` ?

Comment: i found an example that set "tie_selection" to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have nodes pre selected at initial load you need to have `state` property in a node config this way:

```
{
  "id": "nodeid",
  "text": "somestring",
  "state": { "selected": true }
}
```

Check what you are getting from server and feeding to jsTree. Also I don't get what you are doing with this code: `return { 'IdApplication': $('#AppSelectionne').val() };`. But if you want to add the `state` property to the json after downloading you can probably try it with: `return { 'IdApplication': $('#AppSelectionne').val(), 'state': { 'selected': true } };`.

Comment: return { 'IdApplication': $('#AppSelectionne').val() }; is used to get subtree of a node .

Comment: this is the json result from the server

Comment: [{"id":1,"text":"Chapitre","children":[{"id":2,"text":"Affecter Programme","children":null,"state":{"selected"
:true}},{"id":3,"text":"Désaffecter Programme","children":null,"state":{"selected":true}},{"id":4,"text"
:"Consulter Chapitre","children":null,"state":{"selected":true}},{"id":5,"text":"Vérifier les mesures"]

Comment: Everything is in place there. Can you try it without `"tie_selection": false` ?

Comment: I have try a sample example with minimal code in this url http://jsfiddle.net/DGAF4/161/ but its not working i think thre is a  probleme with jstree version

Comment: Check [http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/64uy9fvp/](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/64uy9fvp/). I see selected nodes. Do you?

Comment: thats show that json data are correctly genereted from server. me be the problem is with jstree pluging compatibility because with the same data and the same script still not working

Comment: I assure you there is no problem with jsTree. The json you showed above has some problems - the ending brackets are wrong. The correct one would be: [
            {"id":1,"text":"Chapitre","children":[{"id":2,"text":"Affecter Programme","children":null,"state":{"selected" :true}},{"id":3,"text":"Désaffecter Programme","children":null,"state":{"selected":true}},{"id":4,"text" :"Consulter Chapitre","children":null,"state":{"selected":true}},{"id":5,"text":"Vérifier les mesures"}]}]

Comment: you're right when i comment the jstree refresh it working function ReloadAutorisationTree() {
            $("#AutorizationTree").jstree("close_all");
            //$("#AutorizationTree").jstree('refresh');
        }

Comment: Thanks to you  @Nikolay

Comment: You are welcome. If you solved your issue please accept the answer clicking the check mark to the left of it.